# Anthoncyanins and its maximum absorbance value

Tags: ph, absorbance

Why does maximum absorbance occur for Anthocyanins at the 500 ~ 600nm range. Additionally how can one explain the high absorbance at lower pH for anthocyanins compared to higher pH values ?

Comment: Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to prevent misunderstandings,  need of clarification, objections, downvoting or closure.

Comment: This was heavily downvoted, presumably because you don't provide more background, for instance have you researched the question yourself?

Answer (score -2):

I've actually worked with Anthocyanins before, very fun to observe the color change when the pH of the solution is adjusted.

The color of anthocyanins is a consequence of their molecular structure and their interaction with light in the visible spectrum, specifically in the 500-600 nm range (blue-green to orange-red light).

Refer to this paper for all the specifics:

[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5613902/#:~:text=The%20color%20of%20anthocyanins%20is,in%20an%20increasing%20pH%20condition](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5613902/#:%7E:text=The%20color%20of%20anthocyanins%20is,in%20an%20increasing%20pH%20condition).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).